# PoolDataSource clashes with CommonDataSource

Tags: java, spring, oracle, datasource, ucp

I am trying to migrate a project from Java 8 to Java 11 and I am receiving this error in a PoolDataSource class. Do you have any idea from what it could be?

This is the error I am receiving: 'createShardingKeyBuilder()' in 'oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSource' clashes with 'createShardingKeyBuilder()' in 'javax.sql.CommonDataSource'; attempting to use incompatible return type

Comment: You should [edit] the error message into your question body.

Comment: @Haem, thanks, I chamged it now

Comment: Sounds like a common pattern: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60098095/java-11-migration-createconnectionbuilder-from-pooldatasourceimpl-clashes-wi
Perhaps the DS team in Java is heavily influenced by the work done by UCP team across the floor and copied the API names literally without warning the UCP guys :D